# Is there a method like getClassInfo that includes styles?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I'm using the following code to get an object containing metadata about the application object but it doesn't seem to be listing styles.

```
var classinfo:Object = ObjectUtil.getClassInfo(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication);
```

Is there a way to include styles? And follow up question if there is, is there a way to indicate if the styles are declared locally or inherited /declared in a base class?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be failing to understand how styles work in Flex.

The mxmlc compiler removes the `[Style]` metadata tags when it generates the code for styles. You can verify this by adding the `-keep-generated-actionscript=true` compiler argument and looking for the generated folder in your output dir. (e.g bin-debug). In there have a look at the [YourAppName]-generated.as file. You'll see that it's converted all the style metadata to actionscript.

Here is some code to dump all the style information from the styleManager.

```
for each(var selector:String in styleManager.selectors) {
    var cssStyle:CSSStyleDeclaration = styleManager.getStyleDeclaration(selector);
    var defaultStylesObject:Object = {}
    if(cssStyle.defaultFactory != null) {
        cssStyle.defaultFactory.apply(defaultStylesObject)
    }
    for (var defaultProp:String in defaultStylesObject) {
        trace(selector + " defaultFactory " + defaultProp + ":" + defaultStylesObject[defaultProp])
    }
    var stylesObject:Object = {}
    if(cssStyle.factory != null) {
        cssStyle.factory.apply(stylesObject)
    }

    for (var prop:String in stylesObject) {
        trace(selector + " factory " + prop + ":" + stylesObject[prop])
    }
}
```

You'll have to walk the class hierarchy if you want to see which of these styles are defined in super classes.

Comment: OK I added the keyword -keep-as3-metadata+=Style but still doesn't show up when using ObjectUtils.getClassInfo(). I did a test in the past and when a style was not set (undefined) it did not show up in either of those two properties. I think in my tests if you create a new component, add a style metadata tag to it it does not actually show up in either of those two properties unless it has a value. I think there are some in the SDK that I tested like baseline, baselineShift, top, left, bottom and a few other styles that are not in those properties.